# Get coefficients of a logit model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I have been working on a machine learning project. A few months ago I trained a logistic regression model and saved it using pickle, so I could apply it to my datasets.
I use this code to load the model when I need it.

```
import pickle
infile = open('classifier','rb')
MODEL = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
MODEL

output:
GridSearchCV(cv=RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_repeats=500, n_splits=5, random_state=1234),
             estimator=Pipeline(steps=[('transformer',
                                        QuantileTransformer(random_state=1234)),
                                       ('scaler', RobustScaler()),
                                       ('logreg',
                                        LogisticRegression(penalty='elasticnet',
                                                           solver='saga'))]),
             n_jobs=1,
             param_grid={'logreg__C': [0.1], 'logreg__l1_ratio': [0.1],
                         'transformer__output_distribution': ['uniform']},
             return_train_score=True, scoring='roc_auc')
```

The model is not just the logit but I have different steps.

I would like to get the coefficients of the logit but when I use `.coef_` it gives me an error.

```
logreg = MODEL.estimator.steps[2][1]
logreg.coef_
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the fitted model. To check this, do this:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
check_is_fitted( MODEL.estimator.steps[2][1] )

# NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

To Access the fitted model, you'll have to access the best estimator:

```
check_is_fitted(MODEL.best_estimator_["logreg"])
# None
# None means that it is fitted
```

Now you can get the coefficients

```
MODEL.best_estimator_["logreg"].coef_
```

To elaborate, *coef_* property is not set until *fit()* is called.